# Azure Active Directory service

Tags: azure-active-directory, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I currently embed my Power BI report to my website by create Azure AAD and upgrade power bi user to PRO license, and follow the guideline from [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript). It worked well in testing environment. By this way I can do the filter, each of my customer can only see their data. But I found that if I want to implement in [production environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded-faq) I have to register Power BI Embedded service from Azure. It's quite expensive, the lowest option allow only 300 renders/hour, if I have 100 customers and they often refesh the embedded report, It would hit the limitation.
Is there any other way to embed power bi report to website with lower cost?

Comment: There is no way, to embed Power BI into your website, you must have at least one Power Bi node running on Azure, it's quite expensive.

Comment: with the A1 option from Power BI Embedded service, there are 300 renders/hour. Does this mean if my customer refresh the page 300 times the limitation would be hit?

Answer (score 0):

It is quite expensive. Here is the full list of Power BI embedded pricing:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/power-bi-embedded/

[image]

The PowerBI bills on an hourly rate based on the type of nodes deployed. So if you don't keep your instance active and shut it down after 5 minutes, you'll only owe about 10 cents per month. If you need to have your embedded content loaded all the time this will definitely be a problem, but if you are okay with pausing the service that can save you some money.